# Como hacer la división de los resultados de dos consultas en mysql?

Tags: mysql

Hola quisiera saber si me pueden ayudar con esto tengo 3 tablas de las cuales hago dos consultas para obtener ciertos resultados pero ahora necesito hacer una formula en base a esas dos consultas y la verdad no he podido hacerlas (no se si sera posible también) **la formula seria asi RESUL = MTBF/(MTBF + MTTR)

Esta es la primer consulta:

```
select monthname(Fproceso) as mes,
sum( Hreales) /
sum(case when Paro_mante = 0 then 1 else Paro_mante end) as mtbf
FROM proceso 
group by year(Fproceso), month(Fproceso)
```

y esta es la otra

```
SELECT  MONTHNAME(b.Fecha_ini)  AS Mes, 
        SUM(case when b.Hora_parada = 0 then 1 else b.Hora_parada)  AS Horas,
        IFNULL(p.Paro,0)        AS Paro,
        SUM(case when b.Hora_parada = 0 then 1 else b.Hora_parada) / CASE when p.Paro = 0 THEN 1 ELSE p.Paro END AS MTTR
    FROM orden_trabajo as b
    INNER JOIn solicitud_mante a 
        ON a.Id_soli = b.Id_soli
    -- Subconsulta de "Paros"
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT YEAR(Fproceso) AS anio, 
                      MONTH(Fproceso)  AS mes,
                      SUM(case when Paro_mante = 0 then 1 else Paro_mante end) AS Paro
                      FROM proceso 
                      GROUP BY YEAR(Fproceso), MONTH(Fproceso)
        ) p
        ON MONTH(b.Fecha_ini) = p.mes
        AND YEAR(b.Fecha_ini) = p.anio
    WHERE a.Tipo_mante = 'Correctivo Inmediato'
    GROUP by 
        YEAR(b.Fecha_ini), 
        MONTH(b.Fecha_ini),
        IFNULL(p.Paro,0)
```

Espero me puedan ayudar me he quebrado mucho la cabeza y no logro hacerlo

Comment: Y cual es la relacion entre los datos? o solo queres la cuenta?

Comment: Quiero el resultado pero si me gustaría si me pudieran ayudar que me explicara como se hizo, la tabla **procesos** no tiene ninguna relación con **orden _trabajo ni con solicitud_mante**

Comment: En realidad lo mejor seria que tu vista resolveria los datos. pero si no, igual te pongo una respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo unico que queres es hacer una cuenta con dos campos devueltos por dos selects, lo unico que tenes que haces es un from de ambas tablas (lo cual hace un producto cartesiano entre las tablas, o sea mezcla todos los campos de una con los de otra)

Haces asi:

```
Select a.MTBF/(a.MTBF + b.MTTR) 
from 
   (sum( Hreales) /
   sum(case when Paro_mante = 0 then 1 else Paro_mante end) as mtbf
   FROM proceso 
   group by year(Fproceso), month(Fproceso)) a, 
   (SELECT  SUM(case when b.Hora_parada = 0 then 1 else b.Hora_parada) / CASE when p.Paro = 0 THEN 1 ELSE p.Paro END AS MTTR
       FROM orden_trabajo as b
       INNER JOIn solicitud_mante a 
        ON a.Id_soli = b.Id_soli
    -- Subconsulta de "Paros"
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT YEAR(Fproceso) AS anio, 
                      MONTH(Fproceso)  AS mes,
                      SUM(case when Paro_mante = 0 then 1 else Paro_mante end) AS Paro
                      FROM proceso 
                      GROUP BY YEAR(Fproceso), MONTH(Fproceso)
        ) p
        ON MONTH(b.Fecha_ini) = p.mes
        AND YEAR(b.Fecha_ini) = p.anio
    WHERE a.Tipo_mante = 'Correctivo Inmediato'
    GROUP by 
        YEAR(b.Fecha_ini), 
        MONTH(b.Fecha_ini),
        IFNULL(p.Paro,0) ) b
```